# Regex match, only if colon has been found

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write a regex that matches ports. This works great but often, time gets matched too. I wanted to create negative look-ahead and look-behind so that if there is another colon in the string, it should not match. But I'm making a mistake and I cannot spot it:

[image]

I want the ports to match, but not match times.

```
(?<!:):\d{1,5}\b(?!:)
```

Here is the [link to the saved regex](https://regex101.com/r/GJIVKF/1).

Sometimes, there are ports shown like this :443 and :80 without the IPv4 information. This is why I am looking into the look-around solution. I am using ECMAScript.

Comment: What ECMAScript version does the regex flavor support? Note that even across JS implementations, regex flavors differ (cf. Safari / Chrome).

Comment: @MarioJost I just updated my answer that handles empty IP, all valid IPv4 addresses, and limits ports to valid ports. It now has an ESMAScript example. [Regex match, only if colon has been found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75527888).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does my updated answer work in most browsers? It seemed to work for me in testing across the main three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Javascript and you can make use of variable length lookbehinds, you can assert `:` to the left, but assert not `.` followed by digits and then `:` to the left:

```
(?<=:)(?<!:\d+:)\d{1,5}\b(?!:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4AzXr/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=:)(?<!:\d+:)\d{1,5}\b(?!:)/g;
const s = `10.0.243.7:38518
62.11.21.68:443
01:11:22
21:15:19`;
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

If you want to match the colon as well:

```
(?<!:\d+):\d{1,5}\b(?!:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRF7ke/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<!:\d+):\d{1,5}\b(?!:)/g;
const s = `10.0.243.7:38518
62.11.21.68:443
01:11:22
21:15:19`;
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Comment: Heads up: this detects a number of false positives: https://regex101.com/r/vaQrIj/1

Comment: @JamesRisner Thanks, but apparently it will do for the OPs example data.

Answer (score 1):

##### This regex:

¹

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\K\d{1,5}
```

or

²

```
^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}:\K\d{1,5}
```

Assuming `ip's` are only [ipv4](/questions/tagged/ipv4)

¹ <kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/IxmDe9/1)</kbd>
² <kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hCtowE/1)</kbd>

Comment: Does it works for you?

Comment: it works in a regex tester, but it does not work in SecureCRT where i try to do this. It seems that it cannot handle the /K command. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a regex that matches ports.
> I forgot to mention, that the ports are sometimes displayed without IPs.

ECMAScript regex:

```
^((((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b)){4}|):(?<port>((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4})))$
```

PCRE:

```
^((((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b)){4}|):\K((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))$
```

This handles all the cases including the port shown without an IP address.

See [ECMAScript](https://regex101.com/r/cVOAnG/2) and [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/73bOAL/3) in action.

- First assert the beginning of the string (`^`).
- Then capture a number from 0-9, 10-99, 100-199, 200-249, or 250-255.
- Require a single period after the number and repeat 4 times.
- The word boundary (`\b`) prevents the fourth from matching the `.:` pattern.
- We then reset (`\K`) to ignore the IPv4 address in the match in PCRE and use a named capture in ESMAScript.
- Then we match 0-9, 10-99, 100-999, 1000-9999, 10000-59999, 60000-64999, 65000-65499, 65500-65529, 65530-65535 for the port.
- Finally we assert the end (`$`).

A sample Javascript:

```js
const regex = /^((((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b)){4}|):(?<port>((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4})))$/gm;

const input = `10.0.243.7:38518
62.11.21.68:443
01:11:22
21:15:19
10.20.30.40:2312
10.20..40:2312
10.20.40.:2312
10.20.40:5312
10.20.30.40:0
10.20.30.40:0;
:293
:65536
1.1.2.2:65536`;

for (const match of input.matchAll(regex)) {
    console.log(`${match.groups.port}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in anything after a single `:` in the row:

```
^[^:]*:(\d{1,5})$
```

and use the group 1 for your port.

If you want to be a bit more restrictive and limit the range of ports to the actual 0 to 65535, you could use this:

```
^[^:]*:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[0-5]?\d{1,4})$
```

(for the "sake of brevity ;-)" I allowed leading zeros in this regex)

Comment: Your regex does match great in the tester. Thanks as well for checking the port ranges, this is a nice detail. But i cant use groups in my application, so it will only match the whole line. I was really hoping i could avoid a match alltogether if there is more than one semicolon in the string.

Comment: It will not be possible to do a "not-match" if you don't want to look at the whole line. Maybe you can do a two-step approach where you first match the whole line and then again only the port-number?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Ecmascript here's solution that matches port number standalone or as an ending part of IPv4:

```js
const regex = /(?:\.\d+|\B)(?::)(\d{1,5})\b(?!:)/g;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(?:\\.\\d+|\\B)(?::)(\\d{1,5})\\b(?!:)', 'g')

const str = `10.0.243.7:38518    :440
62.11.21.68:443   port  :80
01:11:22
21:15:19
:443 `;
let m;

ports = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), (m) => m[1])
console.log(ports)
```